# Python-Django error when importing data from settings.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import DB settings from settings.py but I am getting an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Read_Data.py", line 12, in read_bbg
    dbHost = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
KeyError: 'default'

```
import psycopg2
import csv
from django.conf import settings
import sys


def read_bbg(file):
    """
     read from csv and insert into db table 
    """
    settings.configure(DEBUG=True)
    dbHost = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
    dbUsername = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
    dbPassword = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
    dbName = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']

    conn_string = """host='{0}' dbname='{1}' user='{2}' password='{3}' sslmode='require' """.format(dbHost,dbName,dbUsername,dbPassword)
    print(conn_string)
    conn=None

    """
    ##rest of the code##
    """
```

the settings.py is located in ./cf_proj directory and the read_bbg function is in ./coveredfunds/Read_Data.py

Could anyone help me with this error?

Comment: Try to add DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=cf_proj.settings to your environment

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cf_proj")` to your main wsgi file

Comment: does your config contains 
`DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
    }   
}` ?

Comment: Yes it does.
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'secret',
        'USER': 'secret',
        'PASSWORD': 'secret',
        'HOST': 'tenx-dev1.bns',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'require',
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to acquire Django settings outside of configured environment. I guess that is also the reason you have added `settings.configure(DEBUG=True)`, because otherwise you got an ImproperlyConfigured exception?

If you want to configure [Django settings manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module), then your settings are actually empty until you manually configure them. You have configured only DEBUG. You could have configured an ELEPHANT there

```
settings.configure(DEBUG=True, ELEPHANT='big')
```

and now your manual configuration includes DEBUG and ELEPHANT and nothing else is configured.

Anyway, @Jana's answer is on a right track, but you must set default `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` inside this file or function and set it to `"cf_proj.settings"`.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cf_proj.settings')

from django.conf import setttings
import psycopg2, csv, sys

def read_bbg(file):
    dbHost = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
    ... and the rest of the code ...
```